# Using groupby on a function

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a code that calculates the slope of x and y variables (the theil-sen slope) and I want to run this on a list of values based on their group.  My file looks like this:

`station_id year    Sum
210018     1917    329.946
210018     1918    442.214
210018     1919    562.864
210018     1920    396.748
210018     1921    604.266
210019     1917    400.946
210019     1918    442.214
210019     1919    600.864
210019     1920    250.748
210019     1921    100.266`

My output should be:

```
210018: -117189.92, 61.29
210019: 164382, -85.45
```

The code I am using is:

```
def theil_sen(x,y):
    n   = len(x)
    ord = numpy.argsort(x)
    xs  = x[ord]
    ys  = y[ord]
    vec1 = numpy.zeros( (n,n) )
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(n):
            vec1[ii,jj] = ys[ii]-ys[jj]
    vec2 = numpy.zeros( (n,n) )
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(n):
            vec2[ii,jj] = xs[ii]-xs[jj]
    v1    = vec1[vec2>0]    
    v2    = vec2[vec2>0]     
    slope = numpy.median( v1/v2 )
    coef  = numpy.zeros( (2,1) ) 
    b_0   = numpy.median(y)-slope*numpy.median(x)
    b_1   = slope
    res   = y-b_1*x-b_0 # residuals 

    return (b_0,b_1,res)

stat=df.groupby(['station_id']).apply(lambda x: theil_sen(x['year'], x['Sum']))

print stat
```

So `year` is my x variable and `Sum` is my y variable.  The code executes correctly for station 210018 but for 210019 it returns nan.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.theilslopes.html

Comment: there is an error in the scipy theil slope, it does not give the correct results.

Comment: if anyone knows how to do this by writing a loop I would also be happy, it does not have to be with groupby necessarily

Comment: You probably want to remove the for loops (vectorize). FWIW I see a warning when running this code that you are taking the mean of an empty array (presumably this is the cause of the nan). The easiest way to debug this (IMO) is to stick a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` as the first line of the function, call it on the offending group and step through each line 'til you see where the nan happens.

Comment: I played around with this for a couple of minutes.  I think v1/v2 are empty for some data values, in line with what Andy suggests.   Also coef doesn't seem to have any purpose in the code, just fyi.  Anyway, your groupby/apply is probably OK, you just have something wrong with the function itself.

Comment: @spotter could you share how scipy results are inaccurate?

Comment: I have checked it vs. the code above and the USGS KTRLine  slope estimator program and scipy is always incorrect.  It is usually off by about .05.  The function and the USGS program are in agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.argsort(x)` goes for a toss with pandas series. It doesn't work as expected, after the first group because index is no longer from 0-n. Instead work on `x, y` Numpy Arrays.

This works.

```
def theil_sen(x,y):
    x = x.values
    y = y.values
    n   = len(x)
    ord = numpy.argsort(x)
    xs  = x[ord]
    ys  = y[ord]
    vec1 = numpy.zeros( (n,n) )
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(n):
            vec1[ii,jj] = ys[ii]-ys[jj]
    vec2 = numpy.zeros( (n,n) )
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(n):
            vec2[ii,jj] = xs[ii]-xs[jj]
    v1    = vec1[vec2>0]    
    v2    = vec2[vec2>0]     
    slope = numpy.median( v1/v2 )
    coef  = numpy.zeros( (2,1) ) 
    b_0   = numpy.median(y)-slope*numpy.median(x)
    b_1   = slope
    res   = y-b_1*x-b_0 # residuals 

    return (b_0,b_1,res)

stat=df.groupby(['station_id']).apply(lambda x: theil_sen(x['year'], x['Sum']))

print stat


station_id
210018        (-117189.927333, 61.2986666667, [10.3293333333...
210019        (164382.3745, -85.4515, [-170.903, -44.1835, 1...
dtype: object
```

Only addition to existing function are these two lines.

```
x = x.values
y = y.values
```

And, Now, let's see what was the error that was happening, when you apply np.argsort() after first group on series object. Lets take the second group values. Which is -

```
In [70]: x
Out[70]:
5    1917
6    1918
7    1919
8    1920
9    1921
Name: year, dtype: int64

In [71]: numpy.argsort(x)
Out[71]:
5    0
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
Name: year, dtype: int64

In [72]: x[numpy.argsort(x)]
Out[72]:
year
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
Name: year, dtype: float64
```

Since the `ord` is always from `[0-n]`, `x[ord]` for the later groups returns `NaN` values obviously.